# ggplot returning as grayscale instead of the colors I am trying to specify for the overlay

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using the following code to generate a histogram by groups:

```
rap.df<-data.frame(RAPdata)
lastHCT<-RAPdata$HCT_last
rap<-RAPdata$RAP

theme_set(
  theme_classic() + 
    theme(legend.position = "top")
)

ggplot(rap.df, aes(x = lastHCT)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(group = rap), 
                 position = "identity", bins = 20, alpha = 0.4) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800"))
```

The histograms are overlayed, but they are both returning as differing shades of gray, instead of the colors I am trying to specify, and the alpha does not seem to be applied properly. Additionally, I am not seeing the legend at all. Thank you!

Comment: You probably need to use `fill = rap` in your histogram mapping `aes()` function

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Since we don't have data we can't really run the code to see the current output. You don't seem to have a `color=` or `fill=` inside the `aes()` so those scales won't do anything.

Comment: when using `scale_*_manual(values=...)`, it's generally better to use a named list, where the names are the different values in `rap`, and include the variable to be used in an `aes(..)`, as already suggested. For example, try `ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = disp, fill = as.character(cyl))) + geom_histogram() + scale_fill_manual(values=c("4"="red", "6"="blue", "8"="green"))`.

Comment: Side note: unless you are doing something _else_ with the vectors, there is no need to define/use `lastHCT` and `rap`, instead you can do `ggplot(rap.df, aes(x = HCT_last, group = RAP))`. (More so, even if you are doing something else to them, there are many reasons why keeping the modified values as columns in `rap.df` is a good thing.)

Comment: @r2evans it looks like defining the group as a character, then using it to fill the histogram solved the issue. Thanks so much!